# How to pass extension automatically to a Twilio number when called from a regular phone?

Tags: php, twilio

We have a payed Twilio account. For example, for the Netherlands, we have a unique number, which users can call from their phone. This is all ok.

Now, we would like to extend our services, and add/attach many extensions to that single (Twilio) phone number. For every extension, we want to assign (forward to) a real phone number of our agents (also important for statistical and payment reasons). So as an example:

Client browses our page on a mobile phone, he wants to get information about a service, tap on an agent name, and a regular call takes place. Once received the call, Twilio recognizes the extension number, and automatically connects that agent (call his phone number).

The logic should be done with TwiML/PHP combo. The actual problem is this: how to pass the extension into/with the regular call? Already tried to make a `tel:` link with hash (#) and (,) and others, to include the extension, to no avail. Once the link is tapped, only the phone number is passed (at least on Android). Is this even possible?

Also, very important, the extension should be transparent to the clients, as in they should not have any interaction after tapping on the agent (so not choosing - entering digits, from a predefined menu - since there will be tens, maybe hundreds of extensions (so agents), it wouldn't be a practical solution anyway).

With the "Click-to-call" example I've managed to solve that problem, but it's app/browser based, and we need to support regular calls as well.

Any direction/hint is very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I believe in your case, you would either need to do inbound caller id detection and [route the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) as needed or have individual numbers that just forward on as needed.

If it were possible for user intervention then I would suggest an [IVR](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-phone-tree/php/laravel), but I understand that is not what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Actually I was trying to get in touch with someone from Twilio, finally one of the support guys answered me, giving the very same hints/suggestions. So I will need to find another solution. Thank you the same.