# Click to call link with extension?

Tags: android, html, twilio

The problem is simple.

How to create a link (for mobile phone browsers) which would call a phone number, and pass an extension automatically, without intervention from the user?

I am aware of `tel:`, as well as using special signs, such as colon `(,)` to insert a pause, but these work only if I enter them manually on the dialpad (like `+123456789,228`), and not passed by the link itself (not on Android 5.1 anyway).

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

After tinkering a whole lot, found out that on `iPhone 5S` (so sadly no Android), the `comma` (or `p`, which is automatically transformed in comma before the actual dialing takes place), does work as expected, so tapping on a link like this `<a href=tel:123456789,3333>Call</a>` from Safari, it does dial the number, waits for 2 seconds, then enters the extension (3333) automatically. Still searching for the same behavior on Android (or even Windows phones..).

Answer (score 1):

If Twilio is making the call, you can use the [sendDigits parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits).

```
require('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); 

$account_sid = ''; 
$auth_token = '[AuthToken]'; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 

$client->account->calls->create('+441163260745', '+123456789010', 'http://www.example.com/twiml', array( 
    'Method' => 'GET',  
    'FallbackMethod' => 'GET',  
    'StatusCallbackMethod' => 'GET', 
    'SendDigits' => '12345',   
    'Record' => 'false',
```

If calling a Twilio number, then we rely on [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather). But as per your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812814/how-to-pass-extension-automatically-to-a-twilio-number-when-called-from-a-regula/37887840#37887840) and above statements, this does not appear to fit your use case.

Comment: Unfortunately you are perfectly right. Thank you anyways. Upvoted for the effort.